# What scientific theories would support the existence of magic?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, magic, physics

I am working on a dark fantasy world for my board game, and I want to have magic in it, but I have a hard time coming up with "reasonable" ways to explain the existence of magic without it being cheap, like a ''red herring'' or just a deflection.

So I was wondering what not yet proven theories that can be found in physics or other fields could I use to explain the existence of magic that can do seemingly impossible things without destroying already established laws like gravity, etc.

I just want the magic in my world to have a ''sound'' reason for existing. So that when the players are in-game they could suspend their disbelief and not have this constant, nagging thought in their head that all of this is just "bul****.

**UPDATE**:

I looked at some of the answers. I did like quite a lot of them, but
I find it hard to figure out how could they be practically
integrated?

1. I looked into quantum mechanics. As far as I can understand QM is
   more about observations and the measuring process less about being
   able to justify our thoughts alone influencing results.
2. The God idea, especially, if it is presented that the designer or
   the players themselves are Gods is neat. Yet, then just coming up
   with stuff out of nowhere and stating that "we are gods" seems kinda
   cheap. I dunno if people would be interested in that. Even though I
   remember that the "Black & White" games were pretty popular at the
   time.
3. The "use proper context" with Clarks 3 laws is good. I looked at
   the video called "Technomage explains...". It's a nice conversation,
   but I think that this would also come off as a deflection to the
   players. Since in games, the players are making the actions and are
   in control... Whereas in the video (I am assuming) the main
   character had a conversation with someone that they will never be
   able to interact on a level to figure out their "magic". Yet, in my
   game, the players would be the ones that are performing their magic
   to duel each other. If they don`t understand where their magical
   powers come from or how they work, then how can they even perform
   them?

Comment: That will actually depend a lot on your own magic system. What can your magic do? Does it have properly determined limits, that is? Does it require some kind of special energy/material to be used? Is this material/energy found only in the environment or is it also produced by living things (magic through the use of magic stones vs mana system)? These will give us a better understanding of how it works and what it relies on to then determine what it could potentially equate to in real life.

Comment: The answers there are more semantic because, ultimately, magic can fit into one of two camps. Either it's consistent within the laws of nature and thus indistinguishable from science or it's an inconsistent art and therefore cannot be explained. And if it's consistent with nature, then is it really magic? Thus the semantics.

Comment: @ProjectApex I wanted to try tackling this problem from the other side. Rather than coming up with what the magic could do in my fiction, I would start with finding a theory in real life that could support the existence of magic and then extrapolate from there.

Comment: @Halfthawed I have no problem with the answer to this question being a semantic one. The top answer in the linked thread is an acceptable one. Yet, speaking from a gameplay perspective, it might be hard to get people "on the same page" based on a semantic answer. 
Because if we say that magic is unexplainable then it sounds like magic is just based on random probabilities and how can the laws of physics operate without breaking down constantly if magic is not based in nature?

Comment: @Halfthawed If we say that magic is just nature/physics then it needs an explanation. Otherwise, how do all the characters that can use magic can do it consistently without knowing the laws of magic?

An interesting discussion, but players in a game would need an "acceptable" answer.

Comment: Once again, that requires an understanding of what you'd like your magic to do to find a theory. There's been no theory that tackles the potential existence and properties of magic since alchemy died out. If what you want is a more scientific approach, but combined with a magic perspective. Alchemy is the way to go, since it's essentially chemistry with a belief in the supernatural, fruit of the limited scientific knowledge of its time (funny enough, they were right about the possibility of making gold out of other materials, they just couldn't imagine it'd be so much harder than predicted).

Comment: @ProjectApex I do not know if that is true. When people play chess, there are two ways how amateurs usually go about playing the game. They either stress about which opening (first few moves) to choose that will give them the best advantages Or... They stress out about the end-game - concentrating on positions where the king can be checkmated and what they have to do to get to that position. 
I am not asking for a theory that would support the magic system that I have created, instead, I am asking if there any unproven theories that could be used as the basis for whatever kind of magic?

Comment: Magic with a scientific explanation would not be magic at all, it would (by definition) be science.  So you're kinda asking for nothing but "extra physics".

Comment: @StephenG Yeah, I kinda am and that is fine for me.

Comment: Hi Hardrada, the question's been closed as opinion-based. For an indication of the sort of questions which work here you might read the meta discussion of [Catalogue of Question Types](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types). I think I understand what you're getting at, but your question is a request for a list of things (potentially [infinite](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6139#6139)) without the constraints of specific parameters for a best answer. Be specific about what you want to achieve

Comment: (Cont.) You can [edit] the question to tell us of a particular effect you want, and the question'll enter the reopen review queue automatically. You can then ask a series of linked questions in seperate threadsto build-up the picture of your magic system if you wish.

Comment: As I just explained on another closed post, it's worth remembering something Issac Asimov once said: [Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws). You don't need theories, you need context. Consider [the technomage's explanation to Sheridan on *Babylon 5*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjToVZTqCbw). It's one of the best justifications for magic I've ever heard - and there isn't a single discussion of theories. It relies entirely on Clarke's third law.

Comment: This "god idea" is not scientific.

Comment: @Renan Agreed, that is what makes it problematic. It could be used, bit if the players start asking questions of the world then the suspension of disbelief will probably break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I was wondering what not yet proven theories that can be found in physics or other fields could I use to explain the existence of magic without completely destroying already established laws like gravity, etc.

Answer: God is real and he/she/it/them decide what is real and what not.

Theory of creation, it's a theory...not proven, all the requirements you asked for.

And if you are making a game, then technically it is true, you are the god doing the creation and you decided that magic is real.

Answer 2: We live in the matrix, reality is defined by the powers of a computer, someone figured out how to hack reality.

The simulation theory, and if you are talking about a videogame... Then it's actually reality, not only is gonna be technically real but it would be a 4th wall break.

Answer 3: we live in a dream.

Theory of the dream argument....can't be proven wrong and can't be proven right...

Answer (score 2):

### Quantum Field Theory - it's weird, crazy as it sounds, and also truly magical

For realistic magic, look no further than the weird world of [Quantum Mechanics](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/quantum-theory) and in particular [Quantum Field Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantum-field-theory/).

The theory can be summarised thus:

- *All matter and forces we see exist as vibrations* [in fields](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2017/12/20/what-is-a-quantum-field-and-how-does-it-interact-with-matter/#7f9a5e1028c4) that exist all throughout space
- *Particles are [minimum quantities (or quanta)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum) of energy* of each field - currently we have discovered 17 fields (yes that's right, an odd number of 17)
- Particles 'appear' from waves when observed, but otherwise *exist in a state of [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition)* (ie. they are in all positions at once) for which they, for all intents and purposes do actually occupy! We know this, because other fields are influenced by the [probability that it could be there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment).
- The *future, past and present are interchangeable*. In fact, [several experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment) have demonstrated that someone measuring a particles position in the future influences your measurement in the present. Furthermore, some particles (CPT transformation) can be reversed in time, charge or other properties.
- There is no such thing as 'empty space' because fields occupy it. In fact, the probabilistic nature of QFT means that [a region in space 'could' have a particle exist in it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_state), and actually *one could spring into being 'out of nothing', at any time*.

So here are the magical effects that are indeed possible:

- **Particles and objects could literally 'come from nothing'.** Although perhaps improbable, there is still a possibility that assembled particles could exist with no prior warning. In fact, given an infinite range of time, there is a certainty that it indeed will. If probability fields can be manipulated, it may be possible to control this.
- **Time is a reversible property**. An electron travelling a direction is the same as a positron travelling backwards in time. Past events can be influenced by events that have not yet occurred. *There is nothing to say in QFT you can't travel in time both ways.*
- Every particle cannot exist in a precise location. In fact, it is possible for a particle to pass through a wall - its location cannot be closely determined and there is a small **chance the particle would appear on the other side of a solid wall**. This is how fusion occurs in QFT.
- **You could be in many places at once**, until you are observed. A particle is in superposition until it is observed. This is perhaps one of the strangest effects of all - how could indeed a particle on the other side of the planet be possibly influenced by a EM wave in your brain? It can and, according to QFT, it does. Every particle has the 'potential' to influence every other. Once observed, however, this influence 'collapses' and converts the EM wave into a photon.

It is truly an amazing theory - and for all of its fantastical aspects, it is actually the most scientifically successful theory of all time, with almost all of its predictions matching our meticulous observations to-date.

So whatever Magical effect you are after, QFT says there is a random chance that it would occur. The core philosophy of QFT is that our reality is essentially indeterminate (based on probabilities) and not completely determinant. Given an infinity of time it is possible that whatever fantastical effect you need, it will eventually happen.

Comment: I should point out a lot of the quantum weirdness usally only happens on a very small scale

Comment: Dude of course particles can pass through walls. Walls are mostly empty space HAHAHAHA

Comment: @flox Thank you for answering my question. 

From what I gather (and I will read more into this, but...) quantum mechanics could be used as a basis for space/time travel magic?

And to do so I would need to create a method or device that could allow characters to influence waves/fields and/or states?

Our I would need a device/practice on how to create particles from nothing in "empty space"? I am not well-read on the "Big bang", but as another commentator pointed out - maybe Alchemy could be the answer to create a "Big bang" like effect, but on a smaller scale to create particles?

Comment: @Hardrada Tremendous power is awarded to those who can manipulate the fields of QFT. Manipulating the EM / Electron field has allowed us to create the entire industry of electronics. Imagine what is possible if we can manipulate the Quark field, or any of the boson fields. Imagine, indeed, the ability to manipulate probability. It all exists in QFT, and unlocking its secrets can mean significant implications of our reality. Can we create a force from empty space? Yes, get two metal plates 10nm apart and you can create a force equal to an entire atmosphere from 'nothing'. You just need to know.

Comment: (1) Particles are not quanta of energy; there is no such thing as a quantum of energy.  (2) Forces are most definitely *not* any kind of vibrations in any kind of fields. (3) There is nothing special about the reversibility of time in quantum mechanics: time is just as reversible in classical mechanics. You need thermodynamics to understand why time is irreversible.

Comment: @AlexP - Sorry I was using some simplified terms to convey the concept without too much condensed information (I suppose we'd need a whole book to really summarise the theory) and too many complicated terminology. You are indeed correct though - if there could be a longer answer I would write it better.